# Insert values into binary file

Tags: c, file, binary

I need to make a code to insert data in a binary file, I was able to insert data this way.
But I want to make insert more values ​​so I can insert as many as I want WITHOUT OVERWRITING the ones in the file.
How can I do this
Code can be in C or java

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
struct student{
    char name[30];
    int age;
    int test;
}s1;

int main()
{
    FILE* ptr;
    ptr = fopen("FILE.bin","wb");

    if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("NULÇ");
    }
    else{
        printf("FILE Created");
    }

    printf("Name:");
    gets(s1.name);

    printf("Age:");
    scanf("%d",&s1.age);

    printf("Test:");
    scanf("%d",&s1.name);

    fwrite(&s1,sizeof(s1),1,ptr);

}
```

Comment: "WITHOUT OVERWRITING the ones in the file" is unclear given "make a code to insert data in a binary file,".  Please explain more.

Comment: If you want to insert data into the middle of the file, then you need to first read the rest of the file, write your new data, then whatever the rest of the file you read.  You could create new file, copy everything up to where you want to insert data, insert the new data, then copy the rest of old file to the new file.  Rename the new file to the old name.  If you can arrange to append to end then you save yourself pain.  Look into database libraries (lmdb, libdb, gdbm, tokyo (berkeley db), or something like sqlite).

Comment: If you want to simply insert data at the end of the existing binary file, consider using the appending mode - `"ab"`.